# modal not opening when user clicks on modal trigger

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a pretty basic modal function on my website which displays a **like, repost & comment** modal, above the track, in which trigger has been clicked.

However, I have had to set it up in an odd way due to the tracks being displayed procedurally through **PHP**.

This is my simplified **markup**:

```
<div class="f-wave-send">
    <div class="t__trigger-actions"> <!-- this is the modal trigger button !-->
        <span id="trigger-actions-modal"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="f-track__actions" id="track-actions"> <!-- this is the modal !-->
        <div class="close-actions"> <!-- this is the close button !-->
            <span></span>
        </div>
        <div class="f-track-actions-inner">
            <!-- modal contents !-->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This markup is duplicated across the page (to represent each track within the database); similar to **Facebook**'s feed.

This is the **JS** which controls all the modals functionalities:

```
$(".t__trigger-actions").click(function(){ // when one of the modal triggers is clicked
    var parent = $(this).parent();
    parent.find(".f-track__actions").css("display", "block"); // get the modal within ONLY the same container to display
    parent.addClass("modal__open"); // and add the class modal__open to the container
});
$(".close-actions").click(function(){ // when the close button is clicked
    $(".modal__open").children(".f-track__actions").css("display", "none"); // hide the modal
    $(".f-wave-send").removeClass("modal__open"); // remove the modal__open class from the container
});
$(document).bind('click', function(e) { // if user clicks on anything but the main container
    if(!$(e.target).is('.modal__open')) {
        $(".modal__open").children(".f-track__actions").css("display", "none"); // hide the modal
        $(".f-wave-send").removeClass("modal__open"); // remove the modal__open class from the container
    }
});
```

I have commented where possible trying to explain what is going on. But I'll explain here once again;

When a user clicks on one of the **many** modal triggers within the `document`, it will get that triggers modal, and display it (and add the class `modal__open` to it's parent container).

If a user clicks on the close button (or on the document), close that same modal.

I've been stuck trying to figure this out for a little while now, so all help (and suggestions) are appreciated.

Thanks.

**EDIT**:

What I want to happen is, when the modal opens, it ONLY closes when the user clicks out of the modal, OR on the close button (if that makes sense).

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: @Pointy the modal isn't opening? I'm pretty sure I specified that in the title

Comment: I would hazard a guess that the modal is opening but is immediately being closed again. Can you remove that final `bind` and see what happens?

Comment: @DavidG it works if you remove the bind. However, I would prefer it if the modal closes when the user clicks off it :/

Comment: Yes, but the event is also being triggered for elements inside the `.modal__open`, that includes the trigger to open it.

Comment: Don't let the "click" that opens the dialog propagate up to the document level.

Comment: How would I do that? @pointy :) I assumed `e.stopPropagation()`, however, that didn't work when I added it to the `bind`

Comment: That final bind is still being called when you click the open. Your code only checks that the element isn't a `.modal__open`, but not that the element sits *inside* a `.modal__open`.

Comment: @DavidG yeah I tried to fix that by only closing it if the user didn't click on the main container. :/

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?
- Added `closest()` instead of `parent` just in case its not a direct parent.
- Added `e.stopPropagation()` to the 'open' button.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".t__trigger-actions").click(function(e) {
    var topClass = $(this).closest('.f-wave-send');
    topClass.find(".f-track__actions").css("display", "block");
    topClass.addClass("modal__open");
    $(this).next().addClass("modal__open");

    e.stopPropagation();
  });
  $(".close-actions").click(function() {
    $(".modal__open").children(".f-track__actions").css("display", "none");
    $(".f-wave-send").removeClass("modal__open");
  });


  $(document).bind('click', function(e) {

    var container = $(".modal__open");

    if (!container.is(e.target) && container.has(e.target).length === 0) {
      $(".modal__open").children(".f-track__actions").css("display", "none");
      $(".f-wave-send").removeClass("modal__open");
      $(".f-track__actions").removeClass("modal__open");
    }

  });
})
```

```css
.f-track__actions {
  display: none;
}
.f-wave-send {
  border: 2px solid red;
}
.t__trigger-actions {
  height: 40px;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
.f-track__actions {
  height: 60px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
.close-actions {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="f-wave-send">
  <div class="t__trigger-actions">
    <!-- this is the modal trigger button !-->
    <span id="trigger-actions-modal">Open</span>
  </div>
  <div class="f-track__actions" id="track-actions">
    <!-- this is the modal !-->
    <div class="close-actions">
      <!-- this is the close button !-->
      <span>Close</span>
    </div>
    <div class="f-track-actions-inner">
      <input/>
      <!-- modal contents !-->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is semi what I want. You see, when the user clicks on any of the contents within the modal, it still closes. It needs to stay open if the user clicks anywhere within the modal **except** the close button.

Comment: still does the same things :/

Comment: Check my new fiddle :) exact problem that I am facing. try clicking on one of the inputs. also, if you click exit on one of the modals. it will exit out of all of them

Comment: Check it now, It also checks if the contents are child of `.modal__open` before hiding it